# sem retorno no segundo carregamento select option

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var base_url = '<?=base_url(); ?>';

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Evento change   
            $("select[name=laboratorio]").change(function () {
                // Exibimos 
                //$("select[name=data_prova]").html('<option value="">Carregando datas...</option>');
                // Passando tipo por parametro para a pagina                
                //alert(base_url+$(this).val());
                $.post(base_url+"aluno/reserva_av3/busca_data_prova",
                        {laboratorio: $(this).val()},
                // Carregamos o resultado acima para o campo 
                        function (valor) {
                            $("select[name=data_prova]").html(valor);
                        }
                )
            })
        });
    </script>
```

com a função acima carrego a data que está em minha view:

```
<!-- SELECAO DATA  -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="selectbasic">Data da prova:</label>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <select id="data_prova" required = ""  name="data_prova" class="form-control">                  
            </select>
          </div>
         </div>
```

cujo controller carrega as informações:

```
public function busca_data_prova(){     
    $this->load->model("aluno/reserva_av3_model");      
    $data = $this->reserva_av3_model->retorna_data_agendada();

    echo $option = "<option value=''>Selecione a data para realizar sua prova</option>";
    foreach($data as $linha) {
        $datar = $linha->data;
        $DT = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($datar));
        echo $option = "<option value=".$linha->cod_data.">".$DT."</option>";

    }   
}
```

e o model:

```
public function retorna_data_agendada()
{

$laboratorio = $this->input->post("laboratorio");
$consulta = $this->db->query('
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.P_chekin_Geral.cod_lab, dbo.P_chekin_Geral.al_reg, dbo.P_chekin_Geral.cod_data, dbo.P_checkin_Datas.data, dbo.P_checkin_Datas.dia
FROM dbo.P_chekin_Geral INNER JOIN
     dbo.P_checkin_Datas ON dbo.P_chekin_Geral.cod_data = dbo.P_checkin_Datas.cod_data
GROUP BY dbo.P_checkin_Datas.data, dbo.P_chekin_Geral.al_reg, dbo.P_chekin_Geral.cod_data, dbo.P_checkin_Datas.dia, dbo.P_chekin_Geral.cod_lab
HAVING      (dbo.P_chekin_Geral.cod_lab = "'.$laboratorio.'") AND (dbo.P_chekin_Geral.al_reg IS NULL)
ORDER BY dbo.P_chekin_Geral.cod_data
');
return $consulta->result();
```

Isso tudo está funcionando, só que agora o que preciso é que quando eu selecionar a data o select option horario carregue com so horarios predefinidos do banco, só que não está carregando veja:

o script está parecido com o anterior:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var base_url = '<?=base_url(); ?>';

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Evento 
            $("select[name=data_prova]").change(function () {
                // Exibimos                    
                $.post(base_url+"aluno/reserva_av3/busca_horario_agendado",
                        {data_prova: $(this).val()},
                // Carregamos o resultado acima para o campo
                        function (valor) {
                            $("select[name=horario_prova]").html(valor);
                        }
                )
            })
        });
    </script>
```

a view:

```
<!-- SELECAO HORARIO -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="selectbasic">Horario da prova:</label>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <select id="horaio_prova" required = ""  name="horario_prova" class="form-control">                  
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
```

e o controller:

```
public function busca_horario_agendado(){           
    $this->load->model("aluno/reserva_av3_model");      
    $hora = $this->reserva_av3_model->retorna_horario_agendado();

    echo $option = "<option value=''>Selecione o horario para realizar sua prova</option>";
    foreach($hora as $linha) {          
        echo $option = "<option value=".$linha->cod_horario.">".$linha->Descricao."</option>";

    }       
}
```

o Model:

```
public function retorna_horario_agendado($turno)
{   

$dataprova = $this->input->post("data_prova"); 
$laboratorio = $this->input->post("laboratorio");   
$consulta = $this->db->query('
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.P_chekin_Geral.cod_horario, dbo.P_checkin_Horarios.Descricao, dbo.P_checkin_Horarios.Turno, dbo.P_chekin_Geral.al_reg, dbo.P_chekin_Geral.cod_data
FROM         dbo.P_chekin_Geral INNER JOIN
                  dbo.P_checkin_Horarios ON dbo.P_chekin_Geral.cod_horario = dbo.P_checkin_Horarios.COD_HORARIO
GROUP BY dbo.P_chekin_Geral.al_reg, dbo.P_checkin_Horarios.Descricao, dbo.P_checkin_Horarios.Turno, dbo.P_chekin_Geral.cod_horario, dbo.P_chekin_Geral.cod_lab, 
                  dbo.P_chekin_Geral.cod_data
HAVING      (dbo.P_chekin_Geral.al_reg IS NULL) AND (dbo.P_chekin_Geral.cod_lab = "'.$laboratorio.'") AND (dbo.P_chekin_Geral.cod_data = "'.$dataprova.'") AND (dbo.P_checkin_Horarios.Turno = "'.$turno.'")
```

só que não me retorna absolutamente nada, uma vez que na model está tudo ok

Comment: Ola amigo, você consegue debugar seu código? para saber se esta entrando no foreach, por exemplo

Comment: Também reparei que no select "horario_prova" o ID e o NAME estão diferentes, creio que esse não seja o problema, ja que você só usa a propriedade NAME, mas não é uma boa

Comment: consegui exibir sem selecionar a data, mais preciso pegar o valor da data para comparar no select do banco. Não consigo passar esse valor select[name=data_prova]

Comment: Tente debugar e isolar o erro, descobrir em que linha ele crasha, caso n tenha um debugger configurado, tente apenas inserir a URL de retorno no navegador(base_url+"aluno/reserva_av3/busca_horario_agendado", substituindo o base_url claro), e colocar o resultado aqui como um edit, para que possamos analisar pra vc

Comment: O controller:

public function busca_horario_agendado(){  
  $turno = $this->turno;
  $this->load->model("aluno/reserva_av3_model");    
  $hora = $this->reserva_av3_model->retorna_horario_agendado($turno);
  
  echo $option = "<option value=''>Selecione o horario para realizar sua prova</option>";
  foreach($hora as $linha) {   
   echo $option = "<option value=".$linha->cod_horario.">".$linha->Descricao."</option>";
      
  }
  
    
  
 }

Comment: coloquei o restante do codigo lá em cima o model. o problema é mesmo na função java script só preciso pegar o valor da data quando selecionada e pronto, mas a data nao consigo, só consigo pegar o valor do laboratório

Comment: se eu trocar select[name=data_prova] por select[name=laboratorio] e {data_prova: $(this).val()} por {laboratorio: $(this).val()}, ai mostra todas as datas de um vez, mas só queroas datas que foi selecionada no select anterior.

Comment: Já consegui! Obrigado! era só adicionar laboratorio: $('#laboratorio').val()